# Masonry does not work with jQuery in ES6?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, masonry

How can I use masonry-layout with ES6?

ES6:

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';
import Masonry from 'masonry-layout';

class Grid {
   loadMasonry() {
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
             $('.grid').masonry({
                 // options
                 itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                 percentPosition: true,
                 // gutter: 10,
                 // columnWidth: 200
             });
        });
    }
}
```

I have this error:

> Grid.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).masonry is
>   not a function

I have installed it with npm following its [guide](http://masonry.desandro.com/#package-managers):

```
npm install masonry-layout
```

Any ideas why and how to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

This is how I call the class:

```
import Grid from './Grid';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var g = new Grid();

    g.loadMasonry();
});
```

Comment: So you created a class. What did you do next? Where, when and how did you instantiate it?

Comment: @zerkms it works with the vanilla js actually but not with jquery. please see my edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using it as a jquery plugin requires more setup: you need to install a `jquery-bridget` library.

Then, here is a sample code on how to tie it all together from the documentation page:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
var Masonry = require('masonry-layout');
// make Masonry a jQuery plugin
jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );
// now you can use $().masonry()
$('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: 80
});
```

References:

- http://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html#webpack